# Explain surah hajj verse 5

Tags: tafseer, creation, surat-al-hajj

In [Surah hajj verse 5](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/22:5) Allah, the exalted, tells us about the creation of human. In the verse it says we have created the human from clay then Nutffa (sperm) then flesh... my question is Allah is talking about who Adam or humans because Adam can´t be created from Nuttfa because he was the first human. If Allah is talking about humans then how can humans made from clay because humans are first made from (sperm). Can you explain? jazzaakAllah...

Answer (score 4):

The way I see it, in this verse Allah is addressing those who are in doubt about the resurrection by providing them with a simple example which is the creation of human beings.

There are a two possible meanings both of which can be proven to be right:

1.The verse is just stating the certain stages through which a human being comes to existence without implying necessarily that each stage is created from the previous one owing to the fact that the verse did not say: "We indeed created the seminal fluid from clay". Therefore, the verse is referring to the creation of Adam at the first stage: "**We indeed created you from clay**" and then starts explaining the next stages through which all other human beings are created afterwards.

2.If we accept that the verse is suggesting that each stage is created from the previous stage, it will be a clear explanation of human creation in general without having anything to do with the creation of Adam. The reason supporting this concept is the fact that, scientifically speaking, the majority substances composing seminal fluid are derived from soil in a complicated chain food.